# The du Sautoy nilpotent group for an elliptic curve.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

I am reading the paper *A nilpotent group and its elliptic curve: Non-uniformity of local zeta functions of groups* by du Sautoy. In this paper he defines the nilpotent group
$$
G=\left\langle x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,y_1,y_2,y_3\Big\rvert 
\begin{matrix}
[x_1,x_4]=y_3,[x_1,x_5]=y_1,[x_1,x_6]=y_2, [x_2,x_4]\\=y_1, [x_2,x_5]=y_3, [x_3,x_4]=y_2,[x_3,x_6]=y_1
\end{matrix}
\right\rangle
$$
where all other commutators are 1. He proceeds to claim that this group is related to the elliptic curve $Y^2=X^3-X$. This should become clear by computing the following determinant:
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
[x_1,x_4] & [x_2,x_4] & [x_3,x_4] \\
[x_1,x_5] & [x_2,x_5] & [x_3,x_5] \\
[x_1,x_6] & [x_2,x_6] & [x_3,x_6] \\
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
y_3 & y_1 & y_2\\
y_1 & y_3 & 1 \\
y_2 & 1 & y_1 \\
\end{vmatrix}.
$$
Unfortunately, I don't know how to compute the determinant when the values of the matrix are elements of some non-abelian group. I naively tried to compute it as if it was a 'normal' matrix, yielding $y_3^2y_1+y_1y_2+y_2y_1-y_2y_3y_2-y_3-y_1^3$. I am sure this is not the correct expression. Nevertheless, I don't see how an expression in three variables will give me insight in the relation of this group to $Y^2=X^3-X$ (two variables).

Does anyone know how to see this relation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those $y_i$ commute because the group is class 2. You should interpret the 2,3 and 3,2 entries as 0, not 1, which gives $y_1y_3^2-y_1^3-y_2^2y_3$ as the determinant, the projectivized version of that elliptic curve.

Comment: Thank you, but isn't that the projectivised version of $y^2=x-x^3$?

Comment: maybe there's a sign error somewhere, maybe $y_1 \leftrightarrow -x$...